# How to know if the user is still online on the website or offline

Tags: php, mysql, database

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Check if user is offline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5634156/check-if-user-is-offline)

I'm building a community website. Users will login and logout as usually.
I use the attribute status online/offline to set the user's status. But what if a user just clicks the X button or disconnects otherwise without logging out?
it shows login status.How i get to know user is currently  online or not ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have three options:

1. You can assume the user is offline if they don't load a new page within a specific period of time (e.g. 10 minutes). This would be done by keeping a "last page load time" for each user on the server.
2. You can have a script on your pages that fires off an AJAX call every so often to tell the server "I'm still here" - this would use the same logic as #1, but would be somewhat more reliable.
3. You can use a page-unload AJAX call to tell the server when the browser is unloading the page, and mark the user as offline until they load another page.

Answer (score 0):

I would use an ajax to make an update the user`s table (every 5 min), if the last update was at most 4 min he is online, 10 min ago then he just left, greater than 15 offline. Or there is a thred on Node js here [Advice on implementing "presence" for a web site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8661758/advice-on-implementing-presence-for-a-web-site/8662707#8662707)